# HA proxy and spring boot gives status=-1 for uploading videos

Tags: spring-boot, haproxy, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Boot project that includes an API for uploading videos. Within this project, I have implemented a Spring Cloud Gateway named "A" which acts as a reverse proxy for my microservice. Additionally, there is an HAProxy server behind Gateway "A". Similarly, I have another Spring Cloud Gateway named "B" behind the HAProxy server, with another HAProxy server behind Gateway "B".

In my micro-service:

```
    @PostMapping("/{sessionId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadFile(@ValidSessionId @PathVariable("sessionId") String sessionId,
                                           @Validated @ModelAttribute FileUploadDTO fileUploadDTO) {
        fileService.uploadFile(sessionId, fileUploadDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
```

I application.properties file in my micro-service:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

My application.yml file in gateway "A":

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  application:
    name: digital-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 30000
        response-timeout: 45s
        pool:
          max-life-time: 60s
          max-connections: 10000
          max-idle-time: 5s
          name: digital-gateway
        max-header-size: 8192
        wiretap: false
      enabled: true
```

My application.yml file in gateway "B":

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        max-header-size: 2048
        connect-timeout: 60000
        response-timeout: 60s
        pool:
          metrics: true
          max-life-time: 60s
          max-connections: 100000
          max-idle-time: 5s
          name: hamrah-baam-proxy-channel
          eviction-interval: 60s

        wiretap: false
        compression: true
      default-filters:
        - RemoveRequestHeader=X-Forwarded-Proto
        - RemoveResponseHeader=X-Powered-By
      filter:
        secure-headers:
          enabled: true
  netty:
    connection-timeout: 40s
    max-keep-alive-requests: 65000
```

My HA proxies config:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull

        timeout connect 10m  
        timeout client  10m  
        timeout server  10m  

    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http_in
        bind *:9080
        mode http

        option forwardfor
        #log /dev/log local3 info
    log 127.0.0.1 local4 info
        bind-process 1 2 3
        option http-buffer-request
        declare capture request len 40000
        http-request capture req.body id 0
        capture request header X-Forwarded-For len 20
        log-format status=%ST\ request_time=%Tr\ client=%ci\ request='"%r"'\ upstream_addr=%si:%sp\ http_x_forwarded_for=%{+Q}[capture.req.hdr(1)]
        use_backend gateway

backend gateway
        mode http
        timeout http-keep-alive 500
        timeout http-request 10000
        option log-health-checks
        option forwardfor
        option redispatch
        option allbackups
        option httpchk
        http-check expect rstatus (2|3|4)[0-9][0-9]
        balance roundrobin
        server worker1       worker1:30081     check port 30081 
        server worker2       worker2:30081     check port 30081 
        server worker3       worker3:30081     check port 30081

frontend stats
    bind *:8404 #process 1
    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats refresh 10s
    stats show-node
    stats hide-version
```

My problem is that for almost 15% of my requests to upload videos, HA proxy gives status=-1 and I see this log on HA proxy:

```
Aug 13 14:19:10 localhost haproxy[220590]: status=-1 request_time=-1 client=192.168.162.84 request="POST /api/digital/files HTTP/1.1" upstream_addr=-:- http_x_forwarded_for="185.206.224.46,192.1"
```

I see this log on gateway "A", but I'm not sure if this log has something to do with this error:

```
2023-08-12T08:20:22.151+03:30  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [1477255e-2, L:/**.**.***.**:59602 - R:iva-authentication.iva.svc.cluster.local/*************:8081]>

io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: recvAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2023-08-11T11:19:28.005+03:30  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [9d4fe572-8, L:/10.42.106.23:60684 - R:iva-authentication.iva.svc.cluster.local/*************:8081] The connection observed an error, the request cannot be retried as the headers/body were sent

io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: recvAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
```

I don't see any exceptions in my micro-service for these senarios and it's like the request doesn't reach my micro-service and I really don't understand how and why this issue is happening. Is there anything wrong with my configs?